# Matplotlib: what backend to use?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using `matplotlib` to generate plots/figures to be used in Latex articles or beamer presentations.

At first I didn't pay attention to the 'backend' as the default one can generate `eps` as well as `pdf` formats but now I'm wondering what could be the advantages of one over another.

I'm using Latex for the text rendering (`usetex = True`).

`backend = PS` and `backend = PDF` looks exactly the same to me. What should I choose (and why)? What are the other options?

Comment: Try to select labels or use references and you might see the short comings of PostScript.